# Accessor function for std::mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

There are two classes. Class A has a private member `std::mutex m_`. Class B has an instance of class `A` as its member.

The goal is to let class B to be able to use `m_` (which is in class A).

I tried adding an accessor method in class A as below, but it gives error `no matching function for call to 'std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex)'`.

1. Is above error because `std::mutex` is non-copyable?
2. What is the suggested way to expose the `std::mutex` in this case?

```
class A {
public:
    // does not work
    std::mutex getMutex() {
        return m_;
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_;
}

class B {
    A a;
    void someMethod() {
        ...
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(a.m_);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, you might want to ask yourself why are you making mutex private, but want to expose. Those two are mutually exclusive from architecture point of view.

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for raising the question. In this case, there's a data structure in class A that's modified by 2 threads: one spawned in A, another spawned in B. Therefore, in order for the data structure to be used safely, A/B need to share that mutex. Since the mutex lives in A, class B needs to access it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is above error because `std::mutex` is non-copyable?

That is correct.  A `std::mutex` cannot be copied or moved.

> What is the suggested way to expose the `std::mutex` in this case?

In this case, you can just return by reference like

```
std::mutex& getMutex() {
    return m_;
}
```

and use it like

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(a.getMutex());
```